# call parent windows routine in window.opener in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, parent-child

I have a child browser window opened in JavaScript that needs to call a routine in the parent.  I know from other questions that I want to do something like `window.opener.parentFunction()` but when I try to do this, TypeScript, somewhat reasonably, complains that it doesn't know what `parentFunction` is.

How do I properly define that routine so that TypeScript compiles?

Comment: It has to be global to the parent window, i.e. it should be accessible via `window.parentFunc` in the window the child is opened from (via `window.open()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Augment the 'Window' type
interface Window {
    parentFunc(): void;
}

window.opener.parentFunc();
```